# How to get concrete parameters in testing neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

If I want to get it's concrete parameter when I deployed it,like throughput of read/write, hit ratio, queries per second, slow_query, time of per query,  etc. before using NEO4j database, how can I do? My leader want to know why I choose it rather other another database.

Answer (score 0):

you could get some of the statistics like cache ratio etc from the JMX extensions, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/operations-jmx.html, otherwise, you can instrument the Jetty server via an unmanaged extension, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-unmanaged-extensions.html